# Как сделать таймер в игре

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

Я сделал игру на Python (очень простую которую запускаю в cmd)

Версия Python 3.9

Нужно чтобы пока шел таймер, пользователь мог что-то делать.
Пример:
В моей игре героя кусает ядовитая змея и нужно в течении 10 сек. выпить хилку

Таймер должен отображаться на экране (как обратный отсчет) и в это время герой должен выпить исцеляющее зелье если не выпьет, умрет.

time.sleep() тут точно не подходит.
Как я могу сделать такой таймер?

Comment: На чем игра написана? Какие библиотеки?

Comment: Не зная что вы используете можно предложить запустить таймер в отдельном потоке или асинхронно. P.S. Sublime это ide а вопрос про используемые библиотеки например pygame?

Comment: библиотек нет, чисто зашел написал код

Comment: Ну к примеру так: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-timer-modulja-threading/

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, как у вас ввод происходит. Если через `input`, то такое будет сложновато сделать. Лучше пишите на `PyGame`, например, там всё проще будет.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте threading для создания 2-ого потока. Заведите переменную play и поставьте изначально ей значение True. Переменная play - разрешение на игру. То есть когда play = False, то тогда игрок не играет и значит он умер. Создаем функцию:

```
def func():
    global play
    sleep(10)
    play = False
```

И вызываем с помощью:

```
threading.Thread(target=func).start()
```

После этого func запустится отдельным потоком и не будет мешать главному потоку.Но через 10 сек он поменяет значение переменной play.Ну а дальше я надеюсь вы справитесь сами